# Add a custom button for a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I want to display an additional button below the description to a specific product category: "bracelets"
so I developed a piece of code, which does not work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
   if ( is_product_category('bracelets')) {
     global $product;
     echo '<a href="www.test.com">Extra Button</a>';
   }
}
```

Any idea about what's wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not really clear.

1) If you want to display a custom button for a specific product category on product category archives pages below the description of this product category you will use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'extra_button_on_product_category_archives', 20 );
function extra_button_on_product_category_archives() {
    if ( is_product_category('bracelets') ) {
        echo '<a class="button" href="www.test.com">Extra Button</a>';
    }
}
```

2) If you want to display a custom button in single product pages for a specific product category below the short description of this product you will use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'extra_button_on_product_page', 22 );
function extra_button_on_product_page() {
    global $post, $product;
    if ( has_term( 'bracelets', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo '<a class="button" href="www.test.com">Extra Button</a>';
    }
}
```

3) If you want to display a custom button in single product pages for a specific product category below the description *(in the product tab)* of this product you will use:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_button_to_product_content', 20, 1 );
function add_button_to_product_content( $content ) {
    global $post;

    if ( is_product() && has_term( 'bracelets', 'product_cat' ) )
        $content .= '<a class="button" href="www.test.com">Extra Button</a>';

    // Returns the content.
    return $content;
}
```

4) If you want to display a custom button in single product pages for a specific product category below the product tabs, you will use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'extra_button_on_product_page', 12 );
function extra_button_on_product_page() {
    global $post, $product;
    if ( has_term( 'bracelets', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo '<a class="button" href="www.test.com">Extra Button</a>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> For product category archives pages use `is_product_category()`. 
>   For all other cases `has_term()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );
```

Comment: Hello, it still does not work. When I remove the condition it works.

How to trigger a php script under condition?

Answer (score 0):

the following code adds the button before the loop on a product category archive

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'extra_button_on_product_category_archives', 20 );
function extra_button_on_product_category_archives() {
    if ( is_product_category('bracelets') ) {
        echo '<a class="button" href="www.test.com">Extra Button</a>';
    }
}
```